# Как получить параметр запроса

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Есть код:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function useQuery() {
    return useLocation().pathname;
}

export { useQuery };
```

Он возвращает URL подобного вида - `/profile/0x738x1608902095352`.

Как из этого URL можно извлечь `0x738x1608902095352`? Я пытался так:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function useQuery() {
    return useLocation().pathname.match(/(?<=\/)\d+/);
}

export { useQuery };
```

Но это не дало абсолютно никакого результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = "/profile/0x738x1608902095352"


const lastSlashIndex = input.lastIndexOf("/")
const lastUrlRes = input.slice(input.lastIndexOf("/"), input.length - 1)
```

Comment: Ну или во второй строке к ```input.lastIndexOf("/")``` добавить 1 вот так ```const lastUrlRes = input.slice(input.lastIndexOf("/")  + 1, input.length - 1)``` что-бы убрать сам слеш